# Sending mail through python

Tags: python, email, outlook

I have been trying to send a mail from python to Outlook. The body does not appear in the mail. The mail gets send, with the subject. The body is blank. What could be the issue?

Here is my code:

```
import smtplib

    username = "neooooo@example.com"
    password = "@death123"

    print("Logged in ")

    vtext = "nihjdoiwjadv@example.com"
    message = "this is the message to be sent"

    msg = """From: %s
    To: %s
    Subject: Hi
    Body:%s""" % (username, vtext, message)

    print("Connecting to server")

    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.office365.com',587)
    server.starttls()
    server.login(username,password)
    server.sendmail(username, vtext, msg)
    server.quit()

    print("Done")
```

Comment: Did you try to assign a simple string to `msg` like `msg = 'my test message'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The body is not part of the headers, especially there is no header called *Body*.  The body of a mail comes after the headers, separated by a blank line.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. It works for me.

```
import  smtplib,getpass,os
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText

os.system('clear')
msg=MIMEMultipart()
print "---------Python Mail Sender--------\n---------ONLY GMAIL Sender---------"
frm=raw_input("From :  ")
to=raw_input("To : ")
msg['From']=frm
msg['To']=to
msg['Subject']=raw_input("Enter Subnject of mail : ")
text=raw_input("Enter text to send in mail : ")

msg.attach(MIMEText(text))
try :
    mailserver=smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com",587)
    mailserver.ehlo()
    mailserver.starttls()
    mailserver.ehlo()
    mailserver.login(frm,getpass.getpass("Enter you password(Will not be visible as you Enter) : "))

    mailserver.sendmail(frm,to,msg.as_string())
except Exception,e:
    print "ERROR : ",e

finally:
    mailserver.quit()
```